# Код получаемый с помощью requests.get() отличается от кода страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Я пытаюсь получить код [этой страницы](https://www.rusplitka.ru/catalog/plitochnyy-kley-zatirka/) так:

```py
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = requests.get('https://www.rusplitka.ru/catalog/plitochnyy-kley-zatirka/')
    print(response.text)
```

В основном код получается правильный, но у каждого товара есть надпись: имеется он в наличии или нет. В коде, который я получил с помощью питона, такого нет.

В чем может быть проблема? Может эти надписи загружаются не сразу а через некоторое время после загрузки страницы?

Comment: Думаю что данная метка выставляется с помощью javascript. Вы можете анализировать класс элемента: для элемента со статусом "в наличии" он равен "avail"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Может эти надписи загружаются не сразу а через некоторое время после
> загрузки страницы?

Да. Это называется динамическая загрузка контента. Так работают практически все сайты, кроме тех, что написаны в 90-x годах прошлого века и там и остались. Один из распространенных способов динамический загрузки это AJAX запрос, который javascript код странички делает на сервер для запроса дополнительного контента после загрузки и рендеринга основного шаблона страницы. Никакой http клиент вам не вернет полный итоговый код страницы, кроме браузера.
Подсказка: есть специальная библиотека (не только для Python),  которая имитирует (точнее подключается к существующему) браузер через специальный драйвер (для каждого браузера он свой и его нужно устанавливать) может полностью прогрузить весь контент. Называется она selenium.

P.S. Для продвинутых программистов selenium может  и не понадобиться, если уметь разбираться во внутреннем API сайта.

> В чем может быть проблема?

Ваша проблема в незнании современного web-программирования. Нужно начинать учить матчасть.