# Не верный результат при парсинге html страницы при помощи lxml

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, lxml

Имеется код на Python, который парсит страницу https://wordpress.org/plugins/. В коде используется фреймворк `BeautifulSoup` в связке с парсером `lxml`. Страница имеет 4 блока по 4 плагина. Результат парсинга получается следующий - первый блок парсится с плагинами, которых нет на этой странице, остальные блоки парсятся корректно. Первый блок со временем может иметь разные результаты парсинга.

При этом, если вместо `lxml` указать парсер `html.parser`, то страница распарсится корректно.

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
    sections = soup.find_all('section')
    for section in sections:
        header = section.find('h2', class_="section-title").text
        print(header)
        for plugin in section.find_all('article'):
            name = plugin.find('h3').find('a').text
            print('\t', name)

def main():
    url = 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/'
    get_data(url)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

А вот результат выполнения кода:

```
Block-Enabled Plugins
     Five Star Restaurant Reservations – WordPress Booking Plugin
     Gallery, Images, Slider in Robo Gallery
     Easy restaurant menu upload
     Smart Slider 3
Featured Plugins
     Classic Editor
     Akismet Spam Protection
     Jetpack – WP Security, Backup, Speed, & Growth
     Gutenberg
Beta Plugins
     Gutenberg
     Two-Factor
     Preferred Languages
     Application Passwords
Popular Plugins
     Contact Form 7
     Yoast SEO
     Classic Editor
     Elementor Website Builder
```

Парсер `lxml` работает не правильно, или я чего-то не так делаю?

Comment: Ну не знаю, у меня что в браузере, то и скриптом, одно и то же показывает. Возможно, сайт учитывает какие-то куки и прочие параметры и просто показывает разные страницы. Посмотрите, что реально в ответе содержится.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, только что проверил, что возвращает ```requests.get(url).text``` - возвращает не совсем то, что есть на странице. Значит проблема не в ```lxml```.

Comment: Но вопрос теперь звучит по другому - почему ```requests.get(url).text``` возвращает не корректные данные

Comment: Почему вы считаете эти данные не корректными? Может там повторюсь какая-то кастомизация под регион, куки, заголовки... Вы не через какой-то прокси туда ходите, случайно?

Comment: Нет, прокси не использую.

Comment: Видимо это ответ на мой вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160757/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-requests-get-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b

Comment: Да, динамическое изменение страницы тоже может быть.